# SP 2013 On-Premises Integration with Remedy - Case Management

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, integrate-remedy-sp2013

Has anyone worked on any project of integration of Case mangement (Remedy) with SharePoint 2013 On-Premises.

Any pointers of how this is done, would be greatly appreciated.

Do they provide any **SOAP/REST** APIs, from which the data can be accessed and imported into SharePoint

Comment: I understand why its been marked as off-topic,but my thought process is that, if anyone has worked on the same type of integration, can they provide some sample code or specific  scenarios  or challenges they faced using SP 2013.